# Find out which nodes use a specific filter

Tags: 7, input-formats

How could I find out which nodes actually use a specific filter?

My nodes use an input format that has the [Bbcode](https://www.drupal.org/project/bbcode) filter enabled. Now I need to know which (of the several thousand) nodes use BB code, to decide if I still need this filter (in which case I’d switch to [Extensible BBCode](https://www.drupal.org/project/xbbcode), and for that I’d like to have a list of nodes to test if everything works correctly).

Comment: I think you can filter a view results by body format. Did you check it?

Comment: @drupality: I guess you mean the [same as suggested by Vishal Patil](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/150932/9223)? As I wrote in the comments to this answer, I can’t get it to work (I guess it’s because this Views filter is for input formats, not filters of input formats)?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view for nodes & add **Content: Body (body:format)** in Filter Criteria, then set the text format value as `bbcode`.

Comment: I can’t get it to work. I used "Is equal to" and the value "bbcode", but get 0 results (although I know some nodes that use it in the body). I tested it also with "Starts with" and the value "b", but nothing. -- Is this `…:format` filter criteria really for *filters* and not just for *text formats* (like "Filtered HTML")? **Edit:** I created a new format and using its name in "Is equal to" works, so I guess this filter is only for formats, not filters?

Comment: It is text format filter, which can be used in filter criteria of views. Please check if you have limited the view by content type or any other filters.

Comment: I checked it (not limited by content type, no other filters). Just to be sure that we use the same terminology: I have an input format (aka. text format) that is named "Filtered HTML". And this has several filters enabled: "Limit allowed HTML tags", "Convert BBCode to HTML", and "Convert line breaks into HTML". All my nodes use this input format, but not every filter of this format is used in all nodes. -- And when I search for "Contains all words" → "Filtered HTML" than it finds the nodes (i.e., the format, not the filter).